# What happened to the Midnight Commander support for marking files?

Tags: mc

In 2010 someone [requested](http://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2021) that Midnight Commander allow marking files by pressing Shift+up and Shift+down, followed by moving up and down respectively.

This feature was implemented in [version 4.7.3](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/commit/017dbda2d77e7bd987eb218fa95ffc439870601a/).

However (as of the latest version), the feature doesn't seem to exist. Shift+up and Shift+down both have no effect; and the otherwise comprehensive man page doesn't mention this feature.

Has the feature since been removed, or am I missing something?

EDIT: I have no local keymap. `/etc/mc/mc.keymap` contains:

```
[panel]
MarkUp = shift-up
MarkDown = shift-down
```

All other shortcuts work.

Comment: It works for me with MC 4.8.18 and 4.8.21. Do you have a personalised keymap in `~/.mc`?

Comment: I just compiled the `master` revision of `mc` from the GitHub sources, and this seems to work out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

It should still be there, it just got moved around a bit.

[Here](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/commit/017dbda2d77e7bd987eb218fa95ffc439870601a/#diff-0687fbde5e27cca55983fbb3939dc5af) is the keymap from version 4.7.3,

```
[panel]
PanelMarkFileUp = shift-up
PanelMarkFileDown = shift-down
```

[Here](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/misc/mc.default.keymap#L81) is the keymap from the master branch,

```
[panel]
MarkUp = shift-up
MarkDown = shift-down
```

Note: While the name has changed slightly, it should function in the same way.

I would verify that these bindings are set in your local keymap.

Comment: I have no local keymap. `/etc/mc/mc.keymap` contains `MarkUp = shift-up` and `MarkDown = shift-down`, but these key combinations don't work. All other shortcuts work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using Midnight Commander in Terminal on MacOS. To fix this, go to Terminal Preferences > Profiles > [your favorite profile] > Keyboard, then add two new shortcuts. Shift-up should output `\033[1;2A` and shift-down should output `\033[1;2B`.

See this [Apple SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115928/terminal-problem-with-ctrl-arrow-and-shift-arrow-keys) for details.

If you're **not** using Terminal on MacOS, maybe double check that your terminal is correctly sending those keypresses in case it's an analogous issue.